# Sequelize with MYSQL: Raw query returns a "duplicate" result

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have this method that performs a raw query:

```
 Friendship.getFriends= async (userId)=>{

      const result = await sequelize.query(`select id,email from users where 
      users.id in(SELECT friendId FROM friendships where friendships.userId = 
     ${userId})`);

      return result;
   };
```

The result seems to contain the same exact data, but twice:

```
[ [ TextRow { id: 6, email: 'example3@gmail.com' },
TextRow { id: 1, email: 'yoyo@gmail.com' } ],
[ TextRow { id: 6, email: 'example3@gmail.com' },
TextRow { id: 1, email: 'yoyo@gmail.com' } ] ]
```

Only two records should actually be found by this query(id's 1 and 6), yet it returns an array with the same records twice.

Can somebody explain me what's going on here?

Edit: the models:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
   const User = sequelize.define('User', {
     email: { type: DataTypes.STRING, unique: true },    
     password: DataTypes.STRING,
     isActive:{type:DataTypes.BOOLEAN,defaultValue:true}
  });

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
   const Friendship = sequelize.define('Friendship', {
     userId: DataTypes.INTEGER,    
     friendId: DataTypes.INTEGER,      
  });
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try to set query type to SELECT in the second argument.

```
sequelize.query(queryString, {type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT})
```

Comment: Why does a raw query do this without the type?

Comment: As per the documentation of Sequelize, when using raw queries two objects are returned, the second one being metadata about the query. But since this behaviour is dialect specific in MySQL and MSSQL the same object is returned thus resulting in duplicates.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure but try below code.

```
const result = await sequelize.query("select id,email from users where 
      users.id in(SELECT friendId FROM friendships where friendships.userId = 
     ${userId})", {type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT});
```

One more thing : Use join instead of in

Comment: Yeah hehe, thats what the previous commenter wrote..it works. About the join: I was trying to construct it correctly, with no success. My SQL is very rusty. Could u write the join version of that query?

Comment: select id,email from users u inner join friendships f on u.id = f.userId where u.id = ${userId}

Comment: Well that's actually the query i came up with, before switching to the sub query alternative. This one doesn't work properly. It returns the email of the current user ("userId"), instead of the "friend"(some other user). So i basically get a list of friends, with "my own email"

Comment: Can you please share that two table schema. So, we can write perfect query.

Comment: select id,email from users u inner join friendships f on u.id = f. friendId where f. userId = ${userId}

Comment: Yes...silly me...had to use the friendId instead of userId. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR;**

Use a query type to avoid duplicates being returned when the database is **either MySQL or MSSQL**

```
sequelize.query(yourQuery, {type: QueryTypes.SELECT})
```

**Explanation**

I'm answering this question because the two answers available up to this day do not explain why this happens.

As per the documentation of Sequelize:

> By default the function will return two arguments - a results array, and an object containing metadata (such as amount of affected rows, etc). Note that since this is a raw query, the metadata are dialect specific. Some dialects return the metadata "within" the results object (as properties on an array). However, two arguments will always be returned, but for MSSQL and MySQL it will be two references to the same object.

To avoid this behaviour you may tell Sequelize how to format the results using a query type as shown above.